Отличия второй версии aiogram от третьей
Кто уже работал с третьей и второй версией аиограма, подскажите, есть ли существенные отличия в производительности, нагрузке и тд? Или основная разница в измененном синтаксисе и введении новых функций? Есть ли смысла оптимизировать бота под третью версию, если в планах нет использования старсов, а используется по большей части только связь с бд, организация интерфейса (кнопки, считывание сообщении и тд) и платежная система?
